# Does there exist a complex function that that is continuous to a point from every direction except for one?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I would like to know if there exists a complex function that is continuous at a point from every direction except for one. One idea that came to mind is the complex logarithm, however, the issue is that the limit doesn't exist from any direction at $z=0$, even with half-lines removed. I thought about holomorphic functions with singularities. I haven't been able to find an example but maybe essential singularities are an interesting direction? I also considered maps
$ \mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $
but again I have had no luck.

I am not even sure if there even exists such a function but I am curious to find out. Does anybody have any ideas?

**Extention :** I have a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4379113/does-there-exist-a-holomorphic-function-that-is-continuous-to-a-point-from-every) exploring if there exist such holomorphic functions.

Comment: Complex valued. I should clarify that I would like the function to be convergent in some punctured disk about that point.

Comment: Yes, I meant continious

Comment: Could you define direction please? As in straight lines?

Comment: This isn't a set question, it was something that I was curious about. Feel free to interpret it as either a line or any path. I am just curious about the overall nature of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic example $f(x,y)={xy\over x^2+y^2}$ is continuous away from $(0,0)$, and has a limit along every line $y=cx$ for real $c$. But along the line $y=0$, it blows up.

(This can as well be happening on the complex plane, with $f(x+iy)={xy\over x^2+y^2}$, if there are no stronger constraints than continuity.)

This suggests to me that the question really wants to require *more* of the function than just continuity...

EDIT: ok, to have non-existence of a limit along *just_one* ray, in polar coordinates $\theta,r$ with $-\pi/w\le \theta\le \pi/2$, the $f(\theta,r)={1\over r+|\theta|}$ is continuous on the disk, and has limits at the origin except for $\theta=0$. The absolute value on $\theta$ makes the values at $\pm \pi/2$ agree.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. I think this doesn't quite answer the question. For the example you are giving, the limit exists from two directions (approaching through the line $y=0$ from either the left or right directions.

Comment: Ah, true! :)  But/and I'd tend to bet that such an idea can be adapted. Don't k now for sure.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} 1&\text{if } y\neq 0 \text{ or } x\leq0\\0&\text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$ Is this something you had in mind?

Comment: Yes! That answers the question I believe. I will shortly post an extension about holomorphic functions.