# Does there exist a holomorphic function that is continuous to a point from every direction except for one?

Tags: complex-analysis

Earlier today, I posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4378961/does-there-exist-a-complex-function-that-that-is-continuous-to-a-point-from-ever/4379083#4379083) in regards to complex-valued functions which are continuous to a point from all directions but one. One of the answers gives an example of such function, however, it is not holomorphic. This is an extention to the previous question asking specifically:

Does there exist a holomorphic function that is well defined on some open punctured disk, about a point $a$, such that the function is continious at $a$ for all directions but one.

**My Thoughts**
If such function was to exist, I would think that we would require $a$ to be a singularity. Now, from my experience with singularities, I would think that this can not be an essential singularity due to the local behaviour. So I would think that we are after a pole?

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: It certainly cannot be a pole, since the function would approach $\infty$ from all directions at a pole.  But it is not so obvious whether it could be an essential singularity.

Comment: Good point! In regards to essential singularities, my thoughts were that the region about the singularity is dense and I am not aware if a region can be dense along a strip?

Comment: Do you mean the point $a$ does not belong to the domain of the function and you want to know if it can be continuously extended to $a$ for all, but one direction?

Comment: @ManateePink yes, but with the extra condition that the function is holomorphic at all points on some open disc about $a$ except for $a$ itself.